# How can I access, then animate an existing leaflet map polyline using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, animation, mapping, polyline, cloudmade

Can anyone suggest how I can access then animate the red polyline here using javascript:

http://gymloop.lukem.co.uk (login: User2/pass2, then select 'Challenges')

I want to animate the polyline from the first marker to the end of the red line (think Indiana jones but without the map moving and NOT using google maps). It needs to be dynamic as different users will have travelled different distances.

I need thew solution to work in FF, IE7+ & Chrome

I am using cloudmade's [leaflet](http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/) maps and am keen to avoid using google maps.

There is further information in my related question at gis.[stackexchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16168/why-is-my-polyline-on-the-wrong-bearing)

Comment: Why not ask in the developer forums for the product?  This seems really product specific, and not general JS.  I Could be wrong.  http://support.cloudmade.com/developers-forums

Comment: There is no native animation as part of the leaflet product so I need to use something else to do the animation. I'm thinking I may need to duplicate the polylines and overlay some kind of transparent canvas on top of the existing map.

Comment: You mention required support for IE7+, but SVG isn't supported prior to IE9, thus the leaflet maps don't render the paths. If you want a script that would also draw the lines, then you should update your question to reflect that.

Comment: Using something like svgweb to support older browsers would be acceptable at this stage http://code.google.com/p/svgweb/. I will need to test this, though

Comment: Also, the leaflet API seems to suggest that older IEs will fall back to VML. http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/reference.html#polyline

Comment: I don't see a red polyline.  I don't see anything that is red on that map.

Comment: @ gilly3 The page was broken (there are still bugs) but I have reset the user distance now

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've checked out your code and it seems you're using the leaflet API to draw the lines. Because of that, I've decided to write a somewhat generic function that animated those kinds of lines. (By the way, I'm confused why that API uses path tags instead of line tags, but I've rolled with it.)

Here's the code: http://jsfiddle.net/mihaibirsan/Wzvre/

I'd like to polish it a bit more, but I wanted to put a foot in the door for that bounty. :D (I'll get back to polishing and post an update in a few hours, once I've done some other work.)

Comment: Thanks Mihai :) - this looks very promising.

Comment: If you look at the features page, you can see that IE 7-9 are supported http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/features.html

Comment: The features page says IE7-9 are supported, but in fact the paths feature doesn't work on IE7 and IE8. Here are a set of screenshots: [on Chrome](http://www.screenshots.cc/show/51046/173b1), [on IE9](http://www.screenshots.cc/show/51047/a4gg5), [on IE8 via IE9 Dev](http://www.screenshots.cc/show/51048/k9edk), [on IE7 via IE9 Dev](http://www.screenshots.cc/show/51049/r2bgp)

Comment: I think this may have been misleading as the page was broken as the user's total distance was huge. I have reset it now.

Comment: Turns out that I had forgotten to implement an IE css file which contains rules for the VML elements. Will your code work for VML paths do you think?

Comment: It could be adapted to work with VML elements. Show the VML source code when you have it available.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8314028/how-can-i-adapt-this-javascript-to-target-vml-objects-for-internet-explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend [jquery_svg plugin](http://keith-wood.name/svg.html).  I've been using it and there are plenty of features, including animation, text on path, user interaction.

Comment: Thanks. However it seems that with all these libraries e.g Raphael and jquery svg, you can't access or animate anything which you didn't create using that library. Also, I would need to come up with something which works cross-browser.